# PHPUnit ReflectionException Method suite does not exist

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit version 3.6.2, and always got

> PHP ReflectionException:  Method suite does not exist in /pathTo/pear/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php on line 113

when running single test:

```
phpunit path/to/my/ClassToTest.php
```

PHPUnit installed using pear, and I'm using php 5.3.6

are there any php configurations i should fix? 
or this just something that PHPUnit should fix.

the class

```
<?php

class ClassToTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

    public function testSomething(){
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the code in ClassToTest.php.

Comment: Can't replicate this. How are you running the test?

Comment: phpunit path/to/my/ClassToTest.php

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon the same message after enabling xdebug extension.

Try adding this in your php.ini (or comment the line with the 1 for this value) :

```
    ; 0 is actually the default value
    xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using VS Code and getting this exception while trying to debug your unit tests, make sure the **Everything** box is not checked in **Breakpoints** pane. Unchecking that box got me rid of this issue:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To understand why "show_exception_trace=1" causes this problem, see: [Why does PHPUnit hide my xdebug backtrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934216/why-does-phpunit-hide-my-xdebug-backtrace)

Answer (score -2):

xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
works !