# phpunit running exception when run a very very simple unit test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-4

1. I get phpunit and install it as  [this link](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) using the simplest way for test purposes. I just download the phpunit.phar file, chmod & rename & move to /usr/local/bin
   Then, I run **phpunit --version**, its ok.
2. I write a simple php test case.

   ```
   class SimpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
       public function testSomething(){
          $this -> assertTrue(true);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In terminal , I go to my php class folder, and execute

   ```
   phpunit --colors SimpleTest
   ```
4. Now I got the exceptions

   ```
   PHP ReflectionException:  Method suite does not exist 
   in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php on line 113

   PHP Stack trace:
   PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0

   PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main($exit = *uninitialized*)
            /usr/local/bin/phpunit:612

   PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run($argv = array (
            0 =>  '/usr/local/bin/phpunit', 
            1 => '--colors', 
            2 => 'SimpleTest.php'), 
            $exit = TRUE) 
           phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:129


   PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest(
          $suiteClassName = 'SimpleTest',   
          $suiteClassFile = '/home/kevin/Workspace/php/laravel/app/tests/SimpleTest.php',   
          $suffixes = array (0 => 'Test.php', 1 => '.phpt')) 
          phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:150

   PHP   5. ReflectionClass->getMethod('suite')    
   phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:113

   PHPUnit 3.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann.
   ```

Anything is welcome, thanks .

Comment: A little suggestion; run it without colors - just to be sure. And: extend on the class `TestCase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this error comes from an xdebug setting.

The solution appears to be adding this line to your php.ini file (or changing your the existing value to 0):

```
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
```

Take a look at 
[PHPUnit ReflectionException Method suite does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305417/phpunit-reflectionexception-method-suite-does-not-exist) and 
[Why does PHPUnit hide my xdebug backtrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934216/why-does-phpunit-hide-my-xdebug-backtrace) for more info.

Comment: Thanks J.T.  yes, I turn off this config, no exception now.