# Using PHPUnit tests in Netbeans

Tags: php, unit-testing, netbeans, phpunit

I am really new to PHPUnit testing, so I will have a lot of question about it later, but first, go step by step.

I'v tried to follow the following [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html) from netbeans site.

Unluckily, the documentation is a littlebit outdated, and not so precise I think.

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 on Win7 Ultimate 64bit

So, I've created a new project, and under that a `Calculator.php` and copied the code from the tutorial.

Then I right click on that, say, Tools -> Create Tests. In my `test` directory, the skeleton generator creates the `CalculatorTest`.

Documentation forgot to mention to create a `boostrap` to include the `Calculator.php` for the test, but don't get stuck on it, I did it.

Now, I am right click on the `Calculator.php` and says, `Test`. The result is not that what I am expected.

The test results window says: `No test executed`, while the on the right:

`Perhaps error occurred, verify in Output window.`

Sorry for this big bunch of code, I've just want to be sure, you are see what I do, so here is the content of the output window (see below).

What do I am doing wrong, how can I solve this problem?

```
"D:\PHP\php.exe" "D:\bin\phpunit.phar" "--colors" "--log-junit" "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--bootstrap" "D:\Apache\htdocs\unittest\test\bootstrap.php" "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=D:\Apache\htdocs\unittest\test\CalculatorTest.php"
PHPUnit 4.4.2 by Sebastian Bergmann.

....PHP SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ComparisonFailure:  Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4. in phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/sebastian-comparator/NumericComparator.php on line 99
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:619
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:388
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:687
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:731
PHP  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:846
PHP  12. CalculatorTest->testAdd5() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:846
PHP  13. PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals() D:\Apache\htdocs\unittest\test\CalculatorTest.php:81
PHP  14. PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertThat() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert.php:490
PHP  15. PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual->evaluate() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert.php:2214
PHP  16. SebastianBergmann\Comparator\NumericComparator->assertEquals() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php:129
PHP PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException:  Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4. in phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php on line 135
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:619
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:388
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:687
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:731
PHP  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:846
PHP  12. CalculatorTest->testAdd5() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:846
PHP  13. PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals() D:\Apache\htdocs\unittest\test\CalculatorTest.php:81
PHP  14. PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertThat() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert.php:490
PHP  15. PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual->evaluate() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert.php:2214
PHP PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException:  Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4. in phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php on line 135
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:619
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:388


PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException: Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4. in phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php on line 135

Call Stack:
    0.0300     384472   1. {main}() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:0
    0.0340     589312   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:619
    0.0340     592992   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103
    0.3690    1760968   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
    0.3860    2057496   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:388
    0.4100    2068840   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
    0.8230    2443240   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
    0.8250    2443208   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:687
    0.8290    2443952   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
    0.8941    2538768  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->onNotSuccessfulTest() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:816

F

SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ComparisonFailure: Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4. in phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/sebastian-comparator/NumericComparator.php on line 99

Call Stack:
    0.0300     384472   1. {main}() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:0
    0.0340     589312   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:619
    0.0340     592992   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103
    0.3690    1760968   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
    0.3860    2057496   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:388
    0.4100    2068840   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
    0.8230    2443240   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
    0.8250    2443208   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:687
    0.8290    2443952   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
    0.8550    2474128  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:731
    0.8550    2474600  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:846
    0.8550    2474616  12. CalculatorTest->testAdd5() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:846
    0.8560    2474712  13. PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals() D:\Apache\htdocs\unittest\test\CalculatorTest.php:81
    0.8560    2475072  14. PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertThat() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert.php:490
    0.8570    2475072  15. PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual->evaluate() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert.php:2214
    0.8661    2477440  16. SebastianBergmann\Comparator\NumericComparator->assertEquals() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php:129



PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException: Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4. in phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php on line 135

Call Stack:
    0.0300     384472   1. {main}() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:0
    0.0340     589312   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:619
    0.0340     592992   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103
    0.3690    1760968   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
    0.3860    2057496   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:388
    0.4100    2068840   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
    0.8230    2443240   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
    0.8250    2443208   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:687
    0.8290    2443952   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
    0.8550    2474128  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:731
    0.8550    2474600  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:846
    0.8550    2474616  12. CalculatorTest->testAdd5() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:846
    0.8560    2474712  13. PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals() D:\Apache\htdocs\unittest\test\CalculatorTest.php:81
    0.8560    2475072  14. PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertThat() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert.php:490
    0.8570    2475072  15. PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual->evaluate() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert.php:2214



PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException: Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4. in phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php on line 135

Call Stack:
    0.0300     384472   1. {main}() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:0
    0.0340     589312   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:619
    0.0340     592992   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103
    0.3690    1760968   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
    0.3860    2057496   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:388
    0.4100    2068840   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
    0.8230    2443240   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
    0.8250    2443208   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:687
    0.8290    2443952   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
    0.8550    2474128  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:731



Time: 1 second, Memory: 4.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) CalculatorTest::testAdd5
Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4.

D:\Apache\htdocs\unittest\test\CalculatorTest.php:81

FAILURES!
Tests: 5, Assertions: 5, Failures: 1.
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:687
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:731
PHP PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException:  Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 4. in phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php on line 135
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\bin\phpunit.phar:619
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:103
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:151
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:388
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:716
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:687
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:609
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->onNotSuccessfulTest() phar://D:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:816
Done.
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the project (upload it somewhere)? I think your configuration (perhaps in the bootstrap file, perhaps some PHP configuration) causes the output from tests to contain these stracktraces and NetBeans fails to parse such output (thus the "No tests executed")

Comment: You can download it from here: http://vaso.sma.hu/other/unittest/unittest.zip Three files only, the calc, the test and the boostratp.

Comment: At the last test, I deliberate added bad result to test, to check, is the Netbeans reported it me as failed test. If I remove  that, then I've get back the panel with 4 `passed` tests. Is this the way, how to use PHPUnit for testing?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934216/why-does-phpunit-hide-my-xdebug-backtrace . But it works for me even with Xdebug stacktrace...

Comment: @ladar: You are a life saver, I stucked with this for 1.5 days. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, I did answer in NetBeans's bugzilla as well ;)